# How to get exact part where azure search found a match

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

So I have azure search, and when I search for something in the content it gave me all of the text from file. Is there a way to find a part of the content where it found a match? Like one sentence before + sentence with match + sentence after or just index of the start for match and the length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There is hit highlighting feature for exactly this purpose. To use it you specify the fields you want this information on in highlight member of the request (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#request-body)).  In your response you will get some text snippets with text surrounding the matches and the hit work marked with a tag of your choice (defaults to `<em></em>`).

Comment: Can I change the number of sentences that it returns. For now it returns only one? Can I change it to 3, like ne sentence before + sentence with match + sentence after?